# How to place my products on Amazon?

Tags: amazon

I have a shop in magento and I need my products appear on Amazon. I do not know how to start looking on the subject and would like your help. I already have an account with Amazon AWS but I unaware of the next steps. Another thing I'd like to know is if there is a free extension to make this integration.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually the most popular extension for it: http://m2epro.com/

Comment: You have to pay a fee now for M2E for transaction, BoostMyShop.com is completely free